# Why does Keras model.predict() result in different probabilities based on the size of testing data?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, keras

I'm relatively new to Keras and image classification in general and I'm running into an issue that I can't seem to find much information on.

So the gist of it is that I've written a slightly modified version of the resnet50 architecture and am testing it on my own training dataset of 5000 images. The training and testing data has been split into 85% training and 15% testing. The resulting training accuracy is 94.26% and the testing accuracy is 89.02% after 50 epochs. I wanted to verify that model.evaluate was working properly and so I ran `model.predict()` on the testing data and it produced the same predictions. However, when doing `model.predict(test_data[0:3])` to just see the predictions for the first 3 images in the test data, it produces different probability results than before.

For example when doing just `model.predict(test_data)`, I end up getting these predictions for the first 3 images:

```
 [  3.86609372e-06   9.99959469e-01   8.28523935e-06 ...,   3.81386235e-06
    1.04268118e-07   1.21626453e-09]
 [  5.39615750e-03   2.21778057e-04   1.12958644e-02 ...,   1.02706067e-03
    5.01608439e-02   1.12831332e-01]
 [  1.74208861e-08   2.58701675e-07   4.56858857e-07 ...,   4.93999863e-08
    2.00246024e-08   1.40630873e-05]
```

So as you can see for example the very first image would be of class 2 with a 99% predicted chance.

However, when I run `model.predict(test_data[0:3])`, I end up getting different predictions for the same 3 images:

```
 [  1.27427978e-02   9.65294957e-01   1.36477800e-04   2.46044103e-04
    2.07989533e-02   2.01619656e-07   1.09049659e-04   3.54961463e-04
    2.36560169e-07   1.74340403e-05   2.95751437e-04   3.05204480e-06
    7.25281657e-09]
 [  1.03661343e-02   9.70191788e-04   7.98394233e-02   1.37828933e-02
    4.03248608e-01   2.28452999e-02   1.81689449e-02   4.52506207e-02
    4.14442839e-05   6.90634036e-03   5.04679279e-04   3.94435912e-01
    3.63953644e-03]
 [  4.40177857e-04   3.28276951e-06   5.55719156e-03   1.51521107e-02
    2.68901749e-06   2.38441480e-08   8.34578590e-04   5.70602715e-04
    3.51641923e-01   5.26319724e-03   4.39392490e-04   1.80980451e-02
    6.01996779e-01]
```

So as you can see, these probabilities are very different. The first image still does predict a class of 2, but in other cases, it predicts different classes which are flat out wrong but are correct when doing `model.predict()` on the entirety of the testing data. Similarly, if I do something like `model.predict(test_data[0:4])`, it changes again.

I'm so confused on why this is happening. If anyone has any insight or has encountered something similar, I would really appreciate if you could tell me what's going on.

I apologize if this isn't much information to go on, please let me know if there's any further info you need.